# Terminating AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment and deleting database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I want to terminate some environments from Elastic Beanstalk but when I click on terminate environment the following warning appears:

```
Terminating this environment will also terminate its associated resources.

* URL - name-environment.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com will be released.

* Additional resources – any resources associated with this environment will also be terminated.
```

I want to terminate all the environments inside the app ‘App1’ (Region: Ireland) and I want to keep the environments inside the app ‘App2’.

My question is.. Is there a possibility that some of these resources could also be used by other environments? And if this is possible, would I be able to see what environments are using the same resources before terminating the environment?

I also need to delete the database used by the environments that I have to terminate (database ‘staging’) but I need to keep ‘dev-django-db’ and ‘prod-django-db’ databases because they are the databases used by the environments inside the ‘App2’ app.

I can see that all of them share the same VPC and that is why I’m wondering if when I delete the staging database that could affect in any way to the other two databases.

[RDS - databases screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwDJk.png)

Answer (score 1):

The VPC is likely the default VPC for that AWS account and shouldn't be affected by deleting an Elastic Beanstalk app.

If you are intending on keeping any data beyond a short-lived experiment (and certainly in production), it's a good idea to create your RDS databases independently from your Elastic Beanstalk resources. This will ensure that your data isn't tied to the lifecycle of an app/environment. This might mean additional creating/exporting/saving/importing/configuring of database users/credentials for your Django app but will be worth it to save the worry about accidentally deleting a database!

[Relevant documentation.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html)